# Can TJsonSerializer convert JSON to TValue?

Tags: json, delphi, jsonserializer

```pascal
type
  Titem = record
    &type: string;
    value: TObject; // TValue? 
  end;

procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  obj: TArray<Titem>;
begin
  var data := '[{"type":"uint256","value":"0x123"},{"type":"uint32[]","value":"qq"},        {"type":"bytes10","value":"1234567890"},{"type":"bytes","value":"Hello, world!"}]';
  var ser := TJsonSerializer.Create;
  obj := ser.Deserialize<TArray<Titem>>(data);
  for var item in obj do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add( item.&type );
  end;
end;
```

How to convert JSON to an array with `TValue` or `TJSONValue` or `TObject`?

Comment: i want use it to do abiencode work(make dll call by other language).or is there other way?